# How to Convert a linked image with rollover jquery to codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I created a html site that has images that are links, 
the images change on mouseover. I use a jquery function for this.
It all works perfect in HTML, but Im not sure how to combine the anchor and base_url to them when converting them to codeigniter.

I have been at this all day Id really appreciate any help, I am new to codeigniter I could not find any answers on their page or with a google search.

HTML code (works fine):

```
<a href="hotel.html">
<img src="img/image.png" hover="img/hoverimage.png" class="rollover"/>
</a>
```

I can get as far as linking the src image and can apply the class=rollover I just can not figure out how to add the hover="img/hoverimage.png"

```
<?php echo anchor('hotel', img('img/image.png'), array('class'=>'rollover' ));?>
```

Comment: Hi Cryode,

Thank you for your help its much appreciated. 
I agree about keeping it in html html but unfortunately in this case I cant. Im doing work experience and this is just the front end of a more complicated project.

I had tried adding the hover to the array but what happens then is its associated with the link rather than the image this is what the code turns into:

<a href="http://localhost/hotel" class="rollover" hover="http://localhost//img/image.png"><img src="http://localhost/img/hoverimage.png" alt=""/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it working. In short, I had to put the full address of the images rather than calling the base_url within an anchor. Probably a more accurate way of doing it but I spent so much time on this I am just happy it works....

```
<?php echo anchor('homepg/page/hotel', '<img src="http://localhost/websitefolder/img/image1.png"  hover="http://localhost/websitefolder/img/imagehover.png" class="rollover"/>'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't *need* to use CodeIgniter's helpers to generate HTML. If you have working HTML already, then use it. Sometimes using CI's helpers can make the code more complicated, especially if other people need to figure out what it's doing.

To answer your question, the `img()` function accepts an associative array for the image's attributes. So you can specify the attributes similar to the `anchor()` function.

```
echo anchor('hotel', img(array('src' => 'img/image.png', 'class' => 'hover', 'hover' => base_url('img/hoverimage.png'))));
```

Note that this uses the `base_url()` function from the URL helper.

Comment: Hi Cryode,Thank you for your help its much appreciated.

Comment: If you ever have an answer that solves your problem, please mark it as the solution.

Comment: See revised answer based on your comment about the hover attribute being on the wrong element. In the future, if you have a comment about an answer, please add a comment, do not edit the answer.

Comment: ya dearly noted, new to this site.